# Local struct in template function

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2005

The following code reproduces an error that I get in VS2005: I have a template function like

```
template <typename T> bool foo(T x, T y) {
    struct bar {
    public:
        T t;
        bool CompLT(const bar& that) {
            return (this->t) < (that.t);
        }
    };
    bar X, Y;
    X.t = x;
    Y.t = y;
    return X.CompLT(Y); 
}
```

in a header file *A.h*. When I now use the header in two compilation units *B.cpp* and *C.cpp* VS2005 complains with the error

```
error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall `bool __cdecl foo<float>(float,float)'::`2'::bar::CompLT(struct `bool __cdecl foo<float>(float,float)'::`2'::bar const &)" (?CompLT@bar@?1???$foo@M@@YA_NMM@Z@QAE_NABU1?1???$foo@M@@YA_NMM@Z@@Z) is already defined in B.obj .
```

How can I fix this error? Is this a problem with VS2005 or do I have to move the definition of the struct out of the local function scope and make it a template?

Comment: Do you have #pragma once in A.h?

Comment: You could try marking `CompLT` as `inline` (even though that should be automatic). And/or mark `foo` as `inline`.

Comment: I do not think that is the problem, as a template function can be defined multiple times.

Comment: This sounds like a compiler issue. Have you tried this with new Visual Studio or GCC?

Comment: what about making `struct bar` templated by `T`.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error which is what I'd expect. I've heard not so flattering things about VS2005...

Comment: @Johny: If I make the struct a template I must move it out of the function scope which I did not want to do.

Comment: @wilx I just compiled this example with VS2010 and there it works. So it seems to be a problem with the VS2005 compiler.

Comment: It works with GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: Compiles fine on VS 2012 & 2013. Conclusion: stop using prehistoric tools.

Comment: So this problem is definitely a bug in VS2005 - the example itself is valid C++ code. As I can not change the IDE/Compiler right now, I moved the function into a static template class function and defined the inner struct as a private local within that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments being made it is clear that this is a bug in VS2005. As no one could provide some insight into the exact source of the problem I will give my solution: I moved the function into a static template class and defined the inner struct as a private local within that class template.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) ?

Try adding the following and remove any object file (ending with .o)

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

//your header

#endif
```

Comment: This problem is not at all related to multiple definitions.